# JavaFX Table set table cell background on setEditStart

Tags: colors, javafx-2, cell, edit

I have a table with editable cells (Strings) in JavaFX. I want to edit the value of the cells IN the table itself. Now the edit behaviour in FX is a little bit unusual. You have to press enter to commit the edited value. Changing row or cell is not enough. So my idea was to paint the cell background in yellow when I start editing it and remove the yellow color when the user presses enter to remind the user to press enter. But I have some problems to get the cell in the start-edit method. How can I change the color?

Any hint is welcome!

Here is my code

```
TableColumn nameCol = new TableColumn("Name");  
nameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());     
nameCol.setOnEditStart(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Zone, String>>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(CellEditEvent<Zone, String> cell) 
   {
     if(cell.getRowValue() != null)
       //how to get the cell and then ->.setStyle("-fx-background-color:yellow");
   }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on the `setOnEditStart` API, work with the table's `RowFactory`.

```
/**
 * 
 * @author ggrec
 *
 */
private class FXTableRowFactory implements Callback<TableView<FXTableRow>, TableRow<FXTableRow>>
{
    @Override
    public TableRow<FXTableRow> call(final TableView<FXTableRow> arg0)
    {
        return new TableRow<FXTableRow>() {

            @Override protected void updateItem(final FXTableRow line, final boolean empty)
            {
                super.updateItem(line, empty);

                if (line == null)
                    return;

                if (isEditing())
                {
                    this.setStyle(line.getStyleWhenEditing());
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I was imprecise. I want to edit the value of a cell IN the table itself by clicking in the cell. For that I use the setOnEditStart API together with TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(). If I use your approach, how can I add this behaviour to it?